# How to make chart from javascript be responsive inside of HTML div

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am having a hard time trying to make a google charts javascript chart responsive in my html page - the only way it seems to be working when trying to change screen size is to refresh the page. I am trying to make it so when you click and drag the window, the aspect changes accordingly to the screen size. But to no avail! Perhaps someone has encouncted this problem before or maybe it doesnt work for the charts? Thanks!

https://codepen.io/limtu/pen/QWyLGEX

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



       function drawChart() {
       var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B');

       var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dXP9yGEzNlmRxuSwCr2kyMM9CcS5hloIxKvef0RSa10/gviz/tq? 
       gid=0&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
       query.send(handleQueryResponse);

       };
       function handleQueryResponse(response) {
       if (response.isError()) {
       alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
        };

        var data = response.getDataTable();


        var high = ((data.getColumnRange(1).max)); 
        var low = (data.getColumnRange(1).min);
        var dif = high-low;
        var trail_percent = 0.1;
        var trail = (trail_percent*dif);
        var min_trail = 1
        var min_y = 0;
        trail = Math.max.apply(null, [trail,min_trail]);
        var max_price = high + trail;
        var min_price = low - trail;
        min_price = Math.max.apply(null, [min_price, min_y]);











        var options = {
        title: '1D',
        areaOpacity: 0.5,
        focusTarget: 'category',
         animation: {startup: true, duration: 100,easing: 'in'},
         crosshair: {trigger: 'both', orientation: 'vertical', opacity: 1, color : 'fcb247' },
         tooltip:{trigger:'both'},
         series: {0:{color: '#0173a3', visibleInLegend: false}},
         legend: {position: 'none'},


         hAxis: {title: '', 
         format: 'HH:00',
         gridlines:{count : 4, color:'FFFFFF'}},

         vAxis: {minValue: min_price, maxValue: max_price,
         gridlines:{count : 4},minorGridlines:{interval:0}}
         };
         var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
         }
         </script>
         </head>
         <body>
         <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
         </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `vm` for `width`and `vh` for `height`

[can see this page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html)

```
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div> 
//for width and height 100%;

 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 50vw; height: 50vh;"></div> 
//for width and height 50%;
```

Comment: Thankyou, that has made the aspect ratio fit nicely - however it still doesn't respond automatically to the change of screen size if you click and drag the window smaller or bigger.